# Can I upload existing NuGet packages to an Azure DevOps artifacts feed?

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-artifacts, azure-devops-server-2019

I'm currently migrating from TFS 2012 to Azure DevOps 2019 (both on-premise). With the old server, I would manually create NuGet packages from some of our builds, and host these `.nupkg` files on a file share (configured as a package source in Visual Studio). With DevOps, I can obviously automate all of this and push the packages straight into an artifact feed.

The old server needs to be decommissioned, so I would like to move the existing .nupkg files out of the file share into the new artifacts feed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can push existing `.npukg` files to the new feed.

You can create a simple PowerShell script that pushes to the feed all your `.nupkg` files:

```
# If you didn't add the new feed to your NuGet sources so add it:
nuget sources Add -Name "NEW-FEED" -Source "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/org/_packaging/NEW-FEED/nuget/v3/index.json"
# Put all the nugets in one folder and move to this folder
cd path/to/nupkg/folder
$files = dir
$files.ForEach({
  push -Source "NEW-FEED" -ApiKey AzureDevOps $_.Name
})
```